# Facebook:Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in like and comment array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to Retrieve like from facebook.Following code Retrieves all ID .But I get an error **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** for the line **foreach($status['likes']['data'] as $likesData)**

```
$statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');

foreach($statuses['data'] as $status){

   foreach($status['likes']['data'] as $likesData){

   $frid=$likesData['id']; 
   echo  $frid;
   echo  "<br>";
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

not all statuses have likes (just like not all of them have comments) so you need to check first that the status has likes:

```
$statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');
foreach($statuses['data'] as $status){
    if(!empty($status['likes'])) {
        foreach($status['likes']['data'] as $likesData){
            $frid=$likesData['id']; 
            echo  $frid;
            echo  "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to check if you got any statuses at first place!